# how to validate excel sheet(mathematical as well as basic functionalities) using robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Shall I able to validate all the mathematical operations as well as basic excel operations like insert row, delete row, hide row, merge cells etc related to excel sheet using robot framework(test automation).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/zero-88/robotframework-excel looks useful, otherwise you may need to write some python yourself.

Everything you can do with Python you can do with Robotframework.